# Passing shared_ptr to std::function (member function)

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, std-function

The following observer class registers a callback function with a subject via a call to `attach` when its ctor executes. I would like the observer's dtor to unregister the callback function.

How do I pass the same pointer to `detach` as I did to `attach` so that the subject can remove it from its list of observers?

I'm thinking I have to store a `shared_ptr` to `this` but I'm not sure how I get from that to the `shared_ptr` to the member function `callback`.

Can anyone help?

```
Observer::Observer(Subject& subject) : m_subject(subject),
{
    m_subject.attach("cmd", std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>(std::bind(&Observer::callback, this)));
}

Observer::~Observer()
{
    // I tried this initially but realised that the pointer below
    // is different to the one passed to `attach` from the ctor.

    m_subject.detach("cmd", std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>(std::bind(&Observer::callback, this)));
}

void Observer::callback()
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

`attach` and `detach` are declared as follows:

```
void Subject::attach(const std::string& command, const std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>>& callback);

void Subject::detach(const std::string& command, const std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>>& callback);
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't use a `const Subject&` in your ctor parameter list? I'm asking because your obviously copy-constructing a copy anyway.

Comment: @Superlokkus Because `Subject::attach` is not `const`.

Comment: So `m_subject` is a `Subject &`, too? Otherwise you're creating a copy of your subject, and then it's irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, `m_subject` is a `Subject&`.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that you get what you want :-). Please don't forget to mark an answer with accepted ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to also store a copy of the `shared_ptr` in your observer class, as a member perhaps. Then you could you it to give the same pointer to `detach`.

Like this:

```
class Observer {
    //Other Stuff here

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> callback_ptr;
};

Observer::Observer(Subject& subject) : 
m_subject(subject), 
callback_ptr(std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>(std::bind(&Observer::callback, this))
{
    m_subject.attach("cmd", std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>(std::bind(&Observer::callback, this)));
}

Observer::~Observer()
{
    m_subject.detach("cmd", callback_ptr));
}
```

It's worth noting that, as @dkg also mentioned, `make_shared` does always return a new `shared_ptr` for every time it's called, because it's purpose is to "create a new object with the following parameters and return a `shared_ptr` to it". Is roughly equivalent to `shared_ptr(new std::function<void()> (std::bind(&Observer::callback, this))`.
The reason why there is an extra `make_shared` function is to minimize allocations and to guarantee exception safety in a long expression.
If you just want to shared one object, then just distribute a **copy** of your `shared_ptr`.

Comment: That's the solution. Otherwise a new instance is created in the dtor using `make_shared` and the passed shared pointer points to this new instance instead of the one created in the ctor...

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `std::make_shared` it allocates and constructs a new object for you.

In your code, you call it twice, then you have two instances of your object that are not the same.

You could call it once and keep the shared pointer as a member of your class.